# How to create a recordset from SELECT statement (error: Item not found in collection)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to open a RecodSet with a SELECT statement but I keep getting this error message: *Run-time Error 3265 Item not found in collection*.

I'm running this code on a lostFocus event from a field in a Access 2007 form.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim myDB As Database
    Dim myREC As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strRegionsMsg, boolRegionMsg
    Dim strQuery
    Set myDB = CurrentDb

    strQuery = "Select * FROM RTA;"
    Set myREC = myDB!Execute(strQuery)
    'Set myREC = myDB!Recordsets(strQuery)
```

As you cans see, I tried with Recorsets and got the same problem. Also, I ran my query the query builder of Access and it works.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim myDB As Database
Dim myREC As DAO.Recordset
Dim strRegionsMsg, boolRegionMsg
Dim strQuery
Set myDB = CurrentDb

strQuery = "Select * FROM [RTA]"
Set myREC = myDB.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! But whats the diffrence between openRecordset, Execute and Recordsets

Comment: Execute is for action queries, not select queries in Access DAO.

Comment: And, Recordsets is a **collection** of opened Recordsets. Obviously, there is no object with name "Select * FROM RTA"

Comment: Thanks again for the precission